# Ctrl+left/right on micro via SSH+byobu

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, editors, byobu

Locally when opening [`micro` text editor](https://micro-editor.github.io/), <kbd>Ctrl + left/right</kbd> works normally (jump 1 word).

But when running via SSH +  byobu, <kbd>Ctrl + left/right</kbd> gives `[1;5C]` and `[1;5D]`.

<kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd> also didn't work, it suspends the terminal instead of saving and quit.

What's the cause and how to solve this issue?

#### Update

- Local with `byobu` also have similar issue, it gives `[1;5C` and `[1;5D`, but <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd> works fine.
- SSH without `byobu` doesn't have this issue, it's all works properly.

Comment: Ctrl + left/right are Byobu's keybindings to move between panes. You can toggle on/off them with Shift + F12

Comment: @PabloA nice info, that works locally, but doesn't work for ssh+byobu, changing `export TERM=xterm-256color` work tho

Comment: oh alt+left/alt+right works for switching tab on byobu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably about wrong `terminfo` when byobu is active. Try to set your `TERM` environment variable to different value like `xterm-256color` or anything that the server can understand.